# How to use atexit in C++

Tags: c++

I am working in a C++ homework and the instructions say that it would be good to use atexit() as follows:

> *"Make sure that the program exits cleanly if aborted (Using an atexit() handler is a good way to do this)."*

The homework has nothing to do with aborting program execution (it is about memory management), it is only a suggestion but I am not sure how to use it. The reason for handling this situation is because the program might take too long to execute depending on certain parameters when it is run. If it takes too long I may type CTRL-C or another combination of keys to stop execution abnormally.

This is what I have done.

```
void AtExitFunc()
{
    release_allocator();
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    // Set default values.
    int intMemSize = 512;
    int intBasicBlock = 128;

    atexit(AtExitFunc);
    init_allocator(intBasicBlock, intMemSize);
    ackerman_main();
    release_allocator();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the program will release all the allocated memory when closes. i believe atexit() is goot for closing sockets properly, and deleting temporary files if any.

Comment: I think you might want to move the call to `atexit` *after* `init_allocator` - otherwise, you might have a race.

Comment: Two other comments: 1. You probably should check the return value of `atexit` (it can fail). 2. `atexit` is useful for things the OS won't release for you when the app exits; releasing other things (memory, open files, etc.) seems redundant to me.

Comment: The assignment "Make sure that the program exits cleanly if aborted (Using an atexit() handler is a good way to do this)." is no good teaching.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> results in a `SIGINT` signal that, by default, will terminate the process immediately, without calling any function.

As your C library documentation's manual page for `atexit()` explains, the function installed by `atexit()` gets invoked when the process terminates by explicitly calling `exit()`, or by returning from `main()`. This is the only situation when the `atexit()`-installed handlers will get invoked.

Which is fine, since having your program terminated by the operating system pretty much closes the books, and intercepting the signal and invoking your cleanup function (assuming that it's fully reentrant, which would be rather unlikely) accomplishes absolutely nothing useful, anyway. Just pointing out that this has nothing to do with handling a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>.

Anyway, assuming that it is not possible that your `init_allocator()` could ever call `exit()` itself, installing your exit handler either before or after the call to `init_allocator()` is fine.

However, it is slightly better for your `init_allocator()` to handle installing its exit handler by itself, internally. This way, the fact that an exit handler gets installed is completely transparent.

Also, you should make sure that no harm occurs if your `release_allocator()` gets called twice. In your example, it gets called twice, once explicitly from `main()`, and a second time after `main()` returns (since the fact that your `main()` invokes the function directly does not make the installed exit handler magically go away on its own).